# Why am I getting heap corruption destructing my bitmap class? Is the trouble in this inline assembly?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, assembly, heap-corruption

I'm doing image processing and have been working with a [class I pulled from CodeProject called CBitmapEx](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29121/CBitmapEx-Free-C-Bitmap-Manipulation-Class).

The class manages a data buffer and has useful functions for transforming bitmap images. It was designed to work with 32-bit images, but I have modified it slightly as I will describe to work with 24-bit images.

Under only specific circumstances, I am getting a heap corruption error when a CBitmapEx instance's destructor attempts to free the memory which it allocated when it's resolution was set at the time it was created.

I suspect the root of the problem is in a method which includes some inline assembly that will preform a scaled draw  of the contents of another CBitmapEx.

The criteria which which will cause the error are :

- The bitmap's dimensions less than or equal to 416x416. (Tested with
  square sizes only, 417x417 and up are fine)
- I have performed on the bitmap, a scaled draw of another CBitmapEx
  instance of a different size, even by one pixel in either direction.
  The corruption never occurs when the two are the same dimensions.

I'm displaying the destination bitmap in a Direct2D window and there is no visual indication that the scaled draw is failing in any way.

The CodeProject class works on 32-bit bitmaps, but I am working with 24-bit so I had to modify two lines in the 'drawScaled' method's assembly and the result is a visually correct copied image.

In the listing there are two lines :

```
        add edi, 3
        add ebx, 3
```

I changed these from the original :

```
        add edi, 4
        add ebx, 4
```

This change caused the method to work properly when dealing with 24-bit images. My suspicion is that there may be something else in the assembly which is still assuming 32-bit and is at the root of the problem. Can anyone see something like this in the code?

```
void CBitmapEx::drawScaled(long dstX,
                 long dstY,
                 long dstWidth,
                 long dstHeight,
                 CBitmapEx& bitmapEx,
                 long srcX,
                 long srcY,
                 long srcWidth,
                 long srcHeight){
// Check for valid bitmap
if (isValid() && bitmapEx.isValid())
{
    // Calculate destination params
    long _dstStartX = max(0, min(_bih.biWidth-1, dstX));
    if (srcX < 0)
        _dstStartX = max(0, min(_bih.biWidth-1, dstX-srcX));
    long _dstStartY = max(0, min(_bih.biHeight-1, dstY));
    if (srcY < 0)
        _dstStartY = max(0, min(_bih.biHeight-1, dstY-srcY));
    long _dstEndX = max(0, min(dstX+dstWidth, _bih.biWidth-1));
    long _dstEndY = max(0, min(dstY+dstHeight, _bih.biHeight-1));
    long _dstWidth = _dstEndX - _dstStartX + 1;
    long _dstHeight = _dstEndY - _dstStartY + 1;

    // Calculate source params
    long _srcStartX = max(0, min(bitmapEx.getWidth()-1, srcX));
    if (dstX < 0)
        _srcStartX = max(0, min(bitmapEx.getWidth()-1, srcX-dstX));
    long _srcStartY = max(0, min(bitmapEx.getHeight()-1, srcY));
    if (dstY < 0)
        _srcStartY = max(0, min(bitmapEx.getHeight()-1, srcY-dstY));
    long _srcEndX = max(0, min(srcX+srcWidth, bitmapEx.getWidth()-1));
    long _srcEndY = max(0, min(srcY+srcHeight, bitmapEx.getHeight()-1));
    long _srcWidth = _srcEndX - _srcStartX + 1;
    long _srcHeight = _srcEndY - _srcStartY + 1;

    // Check drawing region
    if ((_dstWidth == 0) || (_dstHeight == 0) || (_srcWidth == 0) || (_srcHeight == 0))
        return;

    // Calculate scaling params
    long _height = bitmapEx.getHeight();
    long _pitch = bitmapEx.getPitch();
    long _bpp = bitmapEx.getBpp() >> 3;
    float dx = (float)_srcWidth / (float)_dstWidth;
    float dy = (float)_srcHeight / (float)_dstHeight;
    fixed f_dx = ftofx(dx);
    fixed f_dy = ftofx(dy);

    // Draw bitmap
    DWORD dwDstHorizontalStartOffset = _dstStartX * _iBpp;
    DWORD dwDstVerticalOffset = (_bih.biHeight-_dstStartY-1) * _iPitch;
    LPDWORD lpDstData = (LPDWORD)_lpData;
    LPDWORD lpSrcData = (LPDWORD)bitmapEx.getData();
    DWORD dwDstPitch = _iPitch;

    __asm {
        mov edi, lpDstData
        add edi, dwDstVerticalOffset
        add edi, dwDstHorizontalStartOffset
        xor edx, edx
outer_loop: 
        xor ecx, ecx
        xor ebx, ebx
inner_loop: 
        push ebx
        push edx
        mov ebx, _height
        sub ebx, _srcStartY
        mov eax, edx
        shl eax, 8
        mul f_dy
        shr eax, 16
        sub ebx, eax
        dec ebx
        mov eax, ebx
        mul _pitch
        push eax
        mov ebx, _srcStartX
        mov eax, ecx
        shl eax, 8
        mul f_dx
        shr eax, 16
        add eax, ebx
        mul _bpp
        pop ebx
        add eax, ebx
        mov esi, lpSrcData
        add esi, eax
        mov eax, [esi]
        mov [edi], eax
        pop edx
        pop ebx
        add edi, 3
        add ebx, 3
        inc ecx
        cmp ecx, _dstWidth
        jl inner_loop
        sub edi, ebx
        sub edi, dwDstPitch
        inc edx
        cmp edx, _dstHeight
        jl outer_loop
    }
}
}
```

Comment: One possible reason may be 32 bit line alignment, this can be an issue for 24 bpp bitmap with odd width.

Comment: BTW, do you really believe that this Assembly code performs better than plain C++ code?

Comment: I agree with what I think Alex implies :) - You should just replace this asm with straight c++ - it's unlikely to be (significantly) slower and will be easier to debug.

Comment: Not sure if it's a problem (since the scanlines might be padded), but it looks like you might be accessing one byte past the last scanline when you reach the bottom-right corner, since you move 4 bytes (`eax`) at a time while your pixels are 3 bytes.

Comment: Alex - I'm not sure it of the asm performance. The codeproject class has some commented C++ above the assembly. I've assumed the author likely had some perf motivation for adding the asm but its a good idea to test it.

Comment: I remember I wrote my first Assembly code and got better performance than C++ code - in Debug configuration :( It was 15 years ago... Remove all this crap and write this in C++.

Comment: Make it work, *then* make it work fast. Always in this order.